# Selenium for WPF UI automation testing

Tags: wpf, selenium

Can I use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to do WPF UI automation testing?

Answer (score 9):

Support for WPF automation exists in WPF itself. Check out [AutomationPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer(v=vs.110).aspx). [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/172391/UIAutomation-Coded-UI-Tests-AutomationPeer-and-WPF) might help. [This article](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/07/automation-peers-for-automation-of-wpf.html) is more detailed. All this is good if you want to automate interaction with the UI itself (the usefulness of which is debatable).

Another course of action is to unit test the business logic without touching the UI - if the application uses MVVM then the loose coupling between View and ViewModel should make unit testing a breeze. I get the impression that you're more into automating the UI though.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use [Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) which is based on Selenium.

There is a pretty good introductory blog post by [Scott Hanselman: WinAppDriver - Test any app with Appium's Selenium-like tests on Windows](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WinAppDriverTestAnyAppWithAppiumsSeleniumlikeTestsOnWindows.aspx).

You'll need the [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) that "supports testing Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and Classic Windows (Win32) apps on Windows 10 PCs".

Answer (score -1):

Selenium can be used to automate only web applications. If your WPF is an windows application you can not automate it.

If you WPF application runs in a web browser using XBAP, still you will not be able to automate the application. So the answer is NO.

Comment: For anyone looking for a 'good' tool, Microsoft's free official [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) has been made to mimic Selenium, you spin up a WinAppDriver and find elements by ID etc.

Comment: There are lot of restrictions on using the Microsoft Windows App Driver in corporate environment as it requires Developer access.

Comment: "If your WPF is an windows application you can not automate it." --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/march/test-run-automating-ui-tests-in-wpf-applications